# How to filter a table by a second table attribute on SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, filter

I have a table named `lines`, that has registered every transaction made in every `account` with it's `datetime`. Along with the amount of the transaction the table has the `balance` for that account at that given time. The line registers the date with the hour (`datetime`) when the transaction was made and registers the datetime when the line was created (`created_at`).

So the lines table looks like this:

```
id | account_id | amount | balance | datetime                   | created_at
 1 | ac1        | 5      | 13      | 2020-03-24 08:57:31.195993 | 2020-03-24 08:57:31.195993
 2 | ac1        | 3      | 10      | 2020-03-24 08:57:31.195993 | 2020-03-24 08:57:30.195993
 3 | ac1        | 5      | 5       | 2020-03-24 06:54:31.195993 | 2020-03-24 06:57:31.195993
 4 | ac2        | 6      | 11      | 2020-03-23 08:57:31.195993 | 2020-03-23 08:57:31.195993
 4 | ac2        | 0      | 5       | 2020-03-23 07:57:31.195993 | 2020-03-23 07:57:31.195993
 5 | ac3        | 6      | 13      | 2020-03-24 08:57:31.195993 | 2020-03-24 08:57:31.195993
```

I would like to get the balance of the last transaction of each day for every account.
It's important to mention that sometimes there are two `lines` that have the same `datetime` for an `account`, in that case I want the line with higher `created_at` datetime.
So I would like my output to be:

```
id | account_id | amount | balance | date       | datetime
 1 | ac1        | 5      | 13      | 2020-03-24 | 2020-03-24 08:57:31.195993
 4 | ac2        | 6      | 11      | 2020-03-23 | 2020-03-23 08:57:31.195993
 5 | ac3        | 6      | 13      | 2020-03-24 | 2020-03-24 08:57:31.195993
```

I've managed to do this with lots of `INNER JOINS` but the query is just too slow.

```
SELECT DATE(lines.datetime) as date, lines.account_id as account, lines.balance as balance
FROM lines
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DATE(a.datetime) date, a.account_id, MAX(a.created_at) created_at
  FROM lines a
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.account_id, DATE(b.datetime) date, MAX(b.datetime) datetime
    FROM lines b
    GROUP BY b.account_id, DATE(b.date)
  ) b ON a.account_id = b.account_id AND a.datetime = b.datetime
  GROUP BY DATE(a.datetime), a.account_id
) c ON lines.account_id = c.account_id AND DATE(lines.datetime) = c.date AND lines.created_at = c.created_at
```

I know there must be a better way, just couldn't find it by myself :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to get the balance of the last transaction of each day for every account.

Use window functions:

```
select l.*
from (select l.*,
             row_number() over (partition by account, date(datetime) order by datetime desc, created_at desc) as seqnum
      from lines l
     ) l
where seqnum = 1;
```